# How to use setState from useDerivedValue

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

Im trying to pass translateX.value to parent by setXPos, and im getting an error
"Tried to synchronously call function {bound dispatchSetState} from a different thread."
I tried using `runOnJS(setXPos)(event.translationX)`, but its too slow, and laggy, for my animation.
The only thing that worked was by using interval, with 5ms and its a lot faster than runOnJS, but i am looking for a good solution not a workaround.

```
    const setShow = promps.setShow;
    const setXPos = promps.setXPos;

    const translateX = useSharedValue(0);

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    //       setXPos(translateX.value);
    //     }, 5);
    //     return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    // }, [translateX.value]);

    useDerivedValue(() => {
        setXPos(translateX.value);
    }, []);

    const swipeGestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler<
        PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
        ContexType
    >({
        onStart: (event, context) => {
            // console.log('Start - ', event.absoluteX, ', ', event.absoluteY);
            context.translateX = translateX.value;
            runOnJS(setShow)(true);
        },
        onActive: (event, context) => {
            translateX.value = event.translationX + context.translateX;
            // console.log(event.translationX);
            // console.log('x:', event.translationX, '  y:', event.translationY);
        },
        onEnd: (event, context) => {
            runOnJS(setShow)(false);
            if (Math.abs(translateX.value) <= windowWidth / 3) {
                translateX.value = 0;
            } else if (translateX.value < 0) {
                //left
                translateX.value = -windowWidth;
                runOnJS(reaction)("reject");
            } else if (translateX.value > 0) {
                //right
                translateX.value = windowWidth;
                runOnJS(reaction)("accept");
            }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [useAnimatedReaction](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/advanced/useAnimatedReaction):

```
const translateX = useSharedValue(0);

useAnimatedReaction(
  () => translateX.value,
  (currentValue, previousValue) => {
    if (currentValue !== previousValue)
      setXPos(currentValue);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the same error "Tried to synchronously call function {bound dispatchSetState} from a different thread."

Comment: @PrzepalonyDecybel how `setXPos` is defined in the parent component?